# How to use a vector in class to keep and store data?

Tags: c++, class, vector

I will be thankful for helping me with this case.
I need to use vector in my class to keep data and store them.
assuming  I haven't work with vectors.
please guide me how to do it?

```
class House
{
      private :
             int NumRooms;
             int Area;
             int FloorNumber;

      public :
             void Getdata()
             {
                   cout << "Enter number of rooms in house: ";
                   cin >> NumRooms;
                   cout << "Enter area of house: ";
                   cin >> Area;                
                   cout << "Enter floor number of house: ";
                   cin >> FloorNumber;                
             }

             void Putdata()
             {
                   cout  << "Number of rooms: " << NumRooms << endl;
                   cout << "Area of house: " << Area << endl;
                   cout << "Floor number: " << FloorNumber << endl;
            }
};
```

Comment: Why do you need a vector in your class? Do you mean, use vector to store class objects?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a vector to store your class data, if I got you right.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>    
using namespace std;

class House
{
private:
    int NumRooms;
    int Area;
    int FloorNumber;

public:
    void Getdata()
    {
        cout << "Enter number of rooms in house: ";
        cin >> NumRooms;
        cout << "Enter area of house: ";
        cin >> Area;
        cout << "Enter floor number of house: ";
        cin >> FloorNumber;
    }

    void Putdata()
    {
        cout << "Number of rooms: " << NumRooms << endl;
        cout << "Area of house: " << Area << endl;
        cout << "Floor number: " << FloorNumber << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    vector<House> vec;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
        House temp;
        temp.Getdata();
        vec.push_back(temp);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i)
        vec[i].Putdata();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank alot @user2198121 ;) sorry I dont have enough reputations to like ur answer, but I keep it in mind ;) again thanks alot

Comment: @user3396107, nevertheless you can accept the answer;)